# I am trying to parse JSON from an API, but I keep getting weird characters that invalidate the JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

My code is:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://547os1.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json?ajaxCatalog=v3&resultsFormat=native&siteId=547os1&domain=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golfbox.com.au%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DCalaway%2BParadym%2BDriver%26Search%3DSEARCH&q=Calaway%20Paradym%20Driver"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}, verify=False)

print(json.loads(response.content))
```

And I get weird response data, for example:

> \/attribute_rule_images\/805553_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846035","mpn":"4H671241I200","inventory_level":1},{"option_value_id":197674,"value":"12 Degree","option_id":42044,"option":"Loft","id":585853,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-12D-R-HZRD SIL 50","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805553_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846035","mpn":"4H671241I200","inventory_level":1},{"option_value_id":197676,"value":"Regular Flex","option_id":42045,"option":"Flex","id":585853,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-12D-R-HZRD SIL 50","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805553_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846035","mpn":"4H671241I200","inventory_level":1},{"option_value_id":197680,"value":"Project X HZRDUS Silver 50","option_id":42046,"option":"Shaft","id":585853,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-12D-R-HZRD SIL 50","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805553_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846035","mpn":"4H671241I200","inventory_level":1},{"option_value_id":197672,"value":"Mens Right","option_id":42043,"option":"Hand","id":585859,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-9D-S-HZRD SIL 60","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805559_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846097","mpn":"4H679041J300","inventory_level":4},{"option_value_id":197675,"value":"9 Degree","option_id":42044,"option":"Loft","id":585859,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-9D-S-HZRD SIL 60","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805559_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846097","mpn":"4H679041J300","inventory_level":4},{"option_value_id":197677,"value":"Stiff Flex","option_id":42045,"option":"Flex","id":585859,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-9D-S-HZRD SIL 60","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805559_source_1704882887.jpg","cost_price":556.75,"upc":"194518846097","mpn":"4H679041J300","inventory_level":4},{"option_value_id":197683,"value":"Project X HZRDUS Silver 60","option_id":42046,"option":"Shaft","id":585859,"product_id":41585,"child_sku":"DVR-PARADYM-GRH-9D-S-HZRD SIL 60","price":799.99,"calculated_price":799.99,"retail_price":1069.99,"width":15,"height":15,"depth":125,"purchasing_disabled":false,"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn11.bigcommerce.com\/s-hiuea1t2mw\/product_images\/attribute_rule_images\/805559_source_1

I have tried to use `response.content`, `.text`, `.json()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to parse the "child_sku_options" values from the Json - you can use `html.unescape()` for that and then `json.loads()` on them again:

```py
import json
from html import unescape

import requests

url = "https://547os1.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json?ajaxCatalog=v3&resultsFormat=native&siteId=547os1&domain=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golfbox.com.au%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DCalaway%2BParadym%2BDriver%26Search%3DSEARCH&q=Calaway%20Paradym%20Driver"

response = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    },
    verify=False,
)

data = json.loads(response.content)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for r in data["results"]:
    options = json.loads(unescape(r["child_sku_options"]))
    print(options)
```

Prints:

```json
...
[
    {
        "option_value_id": 218677,
        "value": "Ladies Right",
        "option_id": 46790,
        "option": "Hand",
        "id": 617491,
        "product_id": 45847,
        "child_sku": "DVR-AI SMOKE MAX F W-LRH-12D-L",
        "price": 1069.99,
        "calculated_price": 1069.99,
        "retail_price": 0,
        "width": 15,
        "height": 15,
        "depth": 125,
        "purchasing_disabled": False,
        "image_url": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-hiuea1t2mw/product_images/attribute_rule_images/833327_source_1707118667.jpg",
        "cost_price": 502.17,
        "upc": "197193258254",
        "mpn": "4J261255S101",
        "inventory_level": 4,
    },

...
```

Comment: any idea how I could access specific elements of the outcome? for example to get the value of "depth" as an output of: 125?

Comment: @Prendles You have to iterate over the options and get "depth" form there, e.g. `for o in options: print(o["depth"])`